# modifying login credentials of windows services (services.msc) using .net 2.0

Tags: .net

I'm creating a .net windows application in visual studio 2005 wherein I need to modify the login credentials of the windows services.
Refer to Services.msc -> right click on any service-> properties -> logon tab.
I need to know if there's any API/Class in .net 2.0 that can be used to invoke this logon tab window?
I want to call this screen in my windows application so that i can perform modification on the user credentials.
Assistance required as I'm a newbe to .Net.

Thanks

Comment: Apologies the version should be 2.0,the  .net windows application I'm creating needs to be created on 2005 visual studio hence this restriction.

Comment: You still had the 1.1 tag, I updated it.

Comment: Ok. Does the question makes sense to you now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used [WMI's Change](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384901(v=vs.85).aspx) in the past:

```
public uint ChangeLogonAccount(string serviceName, string user, string pw)
{
    // Service name is not the same as the display name. For example, world wide web publishing service's service name would be "w3svc"
    string objPath = string.Format("Win32_Service.Name='{0}'", serviceName); 
    using (ManagementObject mo= new ManagementObject(new ManagementPath(objPath))
    {
        object[] wmiParams = new object[8]; // WMI_SERVICE_PROPERTY.StartPassword is index 7 so we need an object array of at least length 8
        wmiParams[(int) WMI_SERVICE_PROPERTY.StartName] = user;
        wmiParams[(int) WMI_SERVICE_PROPERTY.StartPassword] = pw;
        return (uint) mo.InvokeMethod("Change", wmiParams);  
    }
}
```

The WMI_SERVICE_PROPERTY Enum used in my example :

```
public enum WMI_SERVICE_PROPERTY
{
    DisplayName = 0,
    PathName,
    ServiceType,
    ErrorControl,
    StartMode,
    DesktopInteract,
    StartName,
    StartPassword,
    LoadOrderGroup,
    LoadOrderGroupDependencies,
    ServiceDependencies
}
```

Comment: i've used the code to change the logon credentials but the credentials dont seem to update. Any suggestions how to go about changing the username and password?

Comment: string objPath = string.Format("Win32_Service.Name='{0}'", "CryptSvc");
 
    using (ManagementObject mo= new ManagementObject(new ManagementPath(objPath)))
       {
        object [] wmiParams = new object[8]; 
        wmiParams[(int) WMI_SERVICE_PROPERTY.StartName] = "Administrator";
        wmiParams[(int) WMI_SERVICE_PROPERTY.StartPassword] = "#welcome123";
        uint ret = (uint) mo.InvokeMethod("Change", wmiParams);
 }

Comment: the only thing that this code is doing right now is displaying the return value

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the managed C# [`ServiceController`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller(v=vs.110).aspx) API does not allow for password maintenance. The native API is [`ChangeServiceConfig`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681987(v=vs.85).aspx) and that is what you should use in your app. Display your own service configuration dialog.

Now, if you want to specifically use Microsoft Management Console (aka. MMC) to manipulate the service (services.msc is nothing but a *specific configuration* of MMC) then you have to use [MMC automation objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa815049(v=vs.85).aspx) model. As COM automation, is fully supported by C# via COM interop.

Answer (score 0):

Check the project ( [Services+](https://servicesplus.codeplex.com/) ) on codeplex it is open source built with vb.net, you can find the change login credential and other features with Windows Services

Comment: thanks for the reply. Can you be a bit more clear as to what to search on the services+ site you mentioned?

Comment: subee, you call call services.msc with: Process.start(services.msc) and your application can use any credential, you can use impersonator, in the Services+ there is impersonator class and an example about calling services.msc